# jquery ajax in meteor returns error object Object

Tags: jquery, meteor

I want to fetch data from a php code located here http://upfashion.pk/quota/rets.php. Here is my Rets.js code

```
 if(Meteor.isClient){

 Template.data.events({

"click" : function(){


    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url:  "http://upfashion.pk/quota/rets.php",
        data: {},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){
            //console.log(data);
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));

        },
        error:function(err){

            console.log("Error: " + err);
        }
    });


 }


  });

}
if(Meteor.isServer){

Meteor.Startup(function(){



});

 }
```

Here is my Rets.html

```
<head>

<title> Rets Data </title>

</head>

<body>

{{> data}}  
</body>


<template name="data">

Get Data From JSON 
<input id="load" type="button" value="GET" />
<br/><br/>

<table style="border:1px solid black;" id="data">
</table>


</template>
```

Here output in console

```
"Error: [object Object]"  Rets.js:23
```

The code is working fine outside of Meteor but in Meteor its showing error in console

Comment: Here in this code first i want to show data output in console.

Comment: what is the code in line  `23` ?

Comment: Use `console.log("Error: ", err)` instead of `console.log("Error: " + err)`, so you can see what the error object says.

Comment: in line 23 there is console.log("Error: " + err);

Comment: replace `dataType: "html"` to `contentType : 'application/json',dataType: 'json'` and use the returned `data` as json without using `JSON.stringify`

Comment: console.log("Error: ", err) show object Object and that object details didnt show any details of error object

Comment: Is your website hosted on the domain `http://upfashion.pk` or some other domain? You cannot do cross-origin calls using AJAX, usually.

Comment: to see the error details replace `err` with `request,error` to be like this `error: function(request,error)`

Comment: user3059001 i did the changes u told me but still the same result.

Comment: @Ronio Hmm... It does in Chrome, I thought that was a standardized behaviour among browsers. Guess I was wrong. One piece of advice then: use another browser (for example Chrome) where you can easily see what an object contains.

Comment: musically_ut yes it is hosted on http://upfashion.pk

Comment: user3059001 this is my code for error. error:function(request,error){
   
    console.log("Error: ",error);
   }

Comment: user3059001 output in console is the same as "Error: " "error"

Comment: i have placed an answer please try it now

Comment: @PeppeL-G L-G can u plz tell me whats that objects says?

Comment: i just updated my answer please try and let me know if its work

Comment: @user3059001 it is giving syntax error in ur code error: function(xhr, status, error) {
     var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
     alert(err.Message);
   }

Comment: try the other example `xhr,err` and post the your replay in my answer please

Comment: i have posted another example for you in my answer let me know if it work

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
  alert(err.Message);
}
```

and

```
error: function(xhr,err){
    alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
    alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
}
```

Look also at this [encosia](http://encosia.com/use-jquery-to-catch-and-display-aspnet-ajax-service-errors/) article for proper error handling.

or you can use `jQuery` get method for example

```
$.get("http://upfashion.pk/quota/rets.php",function(data){
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Comment: i tried ur example of $.get it doesnt show any result means error is still there

Comment: change the link inside the function use another one maybe the problem from you connection or the server is blocked your ip for too many attempts

Comment: I want to get output in console but not working anything here

Comment: Actually the problem is that jquery is working fine outside of meteor but in meteor jquery is showing error. Is anybody here to point me in right direction

Comment: no actually issue is not with installing any packages

Comment: this is the error message which i get. XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://upfashion.pk/quota/rets.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: then try to change this `dataType: "jsonp", ` and `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and add `crossDomain: true,`

Comment: i used dataType:'jsonp' and the error is SyntaxError: missing ; before statement rets.php:1. rets.php returns json which is correct.

Comment: try to change only `dataType` to `html`

Comment: I used datatype to html again the same Error: error message

Comment: have you tried another json link ? try another one maybe this link content deferent php json header

Comment: SOrry rite now i dont have anyother